# Get product ID from class name eg 'productID_123'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added a class to a list of product images eg 'productID_123', I would like to get the number from the end. I need this to be as dynamic as possible the image may have more than one class. This is what I have put together so far, I think I am nearly there just can't figure out the IF:

```
$(".image").each(function(){

    var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);

    $.each( classList, function(index, item){
        if (item === 'productID_') {
            product_id = item.replace("productID_","");
            fetchProductImages(product_id,this.width,this.height);
        }
    });

});
```

Maybe can I enforce that it is an integer that is returned?

I can't use the data-* attribute because the page is written in XHTML Strict and is required to validate.

Comment: Your `if` is testing for an *exact* match. If you used `.indexOf()` to look for `productID_` in the string, it would work. `if( item.indexOf( 'productID_' ) > -1 ) {`

Comment: Both work perfectly. Which is best for performance wise? 

Am I right in also thinking that I would need to declare the image this outside of the each. Like the edited example.

Comment: I wouldn't give performance a second thought in this case. If I was to *guess*, I'd say `.indexOf()`, but the difference (if any) be minuscule unless we're talking enormous sets of data. Do whichever makes more sense to you.

Comment: ...I'm going to roll back your question so that the answer and comments make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```
$.each( classList, function(index, item){
    var matched = item.match( /^productID_(\d+)$/ );
    if (matched) {
        var product_id = matched[1];
        fetchProductImages(product_id,this.width,this.height);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is causing JS errors with Firebug. I commented out each line and the regex is causing the errors

Error: FBTrace is not defined
Source File: chrome://firebug/content/tabWatcher.js
Line: 720

Comment: @Pointy: You have your `.match()` flipped around. It's a method of `String`. EDIT: ...Fixed. ;o)

Comment: Ah ok - it's "match()" from the string and "exec()" from the regex. That's one of those things that I always get backwards :-)

Comment: @Pointy: +1 was just starting learning regex properly and you confused me. was googling :)

Comment: Sorry man :-)  I'm one of those people who always has to look those things up, even though I use them all the time. You can imagine what my life is like using the Java SDK class libraries :-)